# What is wrong with question about Jesus' children?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9727/is-there-any-evidence-that-jesus-had-no-children) because I wanted to give an answer to some guy asking on FB *How do we know that Jesus had no children?* on a place surrounded by reactions like *Yeah, that's the point about Christian lie!*

I was hoping to find an answer, but could not find any. The only mention about Jesus' youth (in age of 12) was in Luke 2.

The first comments and the first answer were just ignoring the question. I thought it is confusing, so I edited it the best way I could. The next comment were complaining about its very low quality, but what could I add? Despite of my effort, I had no positive results in my research. I believe it is irrelevant and bothering to write ten paragraphs of what I think about it. Why don't keep it simple and clear?

The accepted answer was great, but the rest of the topic was just misleading. Please clarify this:

- Did I hit some taboo? If yes, would this be more suitable for skeptics stackexchange?
- I really don't know how to improve the question about which I can not found anything useful and I really don't want to blur it with my personal confusion about it. Any recommendations? There are just downvotes without any hint.

Comment: FWIW, don't take it personally. You question was not clear to some (including me) until it was edited.

Comment: @DanAndrews: can you recommend some less crazy place for this kind of questions then?

Comment: @JanTuroň maybe there should be a ChristianCritic.SE or NonorthodoxChristianity.SE

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything particularly wrong, except that your asking for proof of a negative which is rarely possible. (It's also an area that I'm pretty sure the scripture is silent on, so there is that.

However, the question itself is valid following the edits and I've edited it a bit more to clarify it.

Some more detail on why you think this is relevant would be helpful, but is not required for the question to remain open and constructive. Why should we be interested in answering this question? Why would it be important if someone wanted to claim they had Jesus' blood in their veins?

Comment: Agreed. At the start I really couldn't work the question out, but after all the edits it became clear to me. So, thanks for helping out, editors!

Comment: Thanks, I have clarified this.

Answer (score 2):

The taboo part is that some self-proclaimed "Christian" religions teach that Jesus had physical children on earth with physical wives, and that belief is very much a core part of their religion. Many of their core beliefs would be invalidated if it were proven that Jesus did not marry and did not have children. On the other hand, many other self-proclaimed "Christian" religions hold that Jesus did not have children, and while that belief is not absolutely essential to their doctrine, it would certainly muddy the waters if it was proven that He did have a wife and children, due to reasons which I have posted on your linked question.